# Jenkins pipeline: log the command that executed in a shell file

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

In the jenkins pipeline, I called a shell file for execute deployment.
While to check it command executed correctly, I would like to check the command log in the console.
But the command in the shell file is not logged.

```
pipeline {
    stages {
        ... // setting environment variable
        ...
        stage('Deploy') {
            steps{
                echo "Deploy"
                script {
                    dir('src/main/resources/my/shell'){
                        sh("./deployShell.sh ${myInput}") // this is logged as + ./deployShell.sh '[my_parameters]'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

//deployShell.sh
...
eb use ${Eb_Name} --region ${Eb_region}  // any command in this file is not logged
...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the output of a shell script in a Jenkinsfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50615649/how-to-get-the-output-of-a-shell-script-in-a-jenkinsfile)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the below line at the top of your shell script

```
#!/bin/sh -xe
```

This should enable verbose logging in your script