# How to get the output of a shell script in a Jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

In a Jenkinsfile Groovy script stage, say I want to issue a linux command that outputs rows and columns of strings, and want to get the nth column in the output of a certain row. An example of such command is "ls -al." So I do this correct?

```
stage("Get dir size") {
  sh returnStatus: true, script: '''
    LINE=`ls -al | grep some_dir`
    IFS=" " read -ra COLS <<< $LINE
    echo ${COLS[4]}
  '''
  /* I want to use the value of ${COL[4]} after above block */
}
```

But how do I get the value of essentially ${COL[4]}, which is the fifth column in an "ls -al" command, which is the directory size?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This bash script you have shown in your example won't return correct directory size. It will return a size of a file, usually `4096` bytes and not a total size of all files and subdirectories recursively. If you want to get the total directory size you can try something like this:

```
#!groovy

node('master') {

  stage("Get dir size") {
    script {
      DIR_SIZE = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'du -sb /var/jenkins_home/war/jsbundles | cut -f1')
    }
    echo "dir size = ${DIR_SIZE}"
  }
}
```

Crucial part is to use `sh` step with `returnStdout` enabled so you can capture inside a variable what the script prints out to the console. In this example I am calculating a total size of `/var/jenkins_home/war/jsbundles` folder and when I run this pipeline script I get:

```
dir size = 653136
```

You can then use `DIR_SIZE` variable as an input in later pipeline steps.

### Alternative approach: using Groovy's `File.directorySize()`

Instead of using a bash script you could consider using Groovy's built-in method `File.directorySize()`, something like:

```
#!groovy

node('master') {

  stage("Get dir size") {
    script {
      DIR_SIZE = new File('/var/jenkins_home/war/jsbundles').directorySize()
    }
    echo "dir size = ${DIR_SIZE}"
  }
}
```

However, this approach will give you a different result comparing to the use case with bash command:

```
dir size = 649040
```

This is because Groovy's `File.directorySize()` method calculates the result as a sum of all file sizes recursively and it does not take into account size of directory file. In this example the difference is `4096` - a size of a directory file `/var/jenkins_home/war/jsbundles` (this path does not contain any subfolders, only bunch of files).

#### Update: extracting data from column-like output

You can extract any information from column-like output by piping commands like `grep` and `cut` together. For example, you can replace above examples with:

```
#!groovy

node('master') {
  stage("Get dir size") {
    script {
      DIR_SIZE = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'ls -la /var | grep jenkins_home | cut -d " " -f5')
    }
    echo "dir size = ${DIR_SIZE}"
  }
}
```

And for following output:

```
total 60
drwxr-xr-x  1 root    root    4096 Nov  4  2017 .
drwxr-xr-x  1 root    root    4096 May 31 03:27 ..
drwxr-xr-x  1 root    root    4096 Nov  4  2017 cache
dr-xr-xr-x  2 root    root    4096 May  9  2017 empty
drwxr-xr-x  2 root    root    4096 Nov  4  2017 git
drwxrwxr-x 20 jenkins jenkins 4096 May 31 12:26 jenkins_home
drwxr-xr-x  5 root    root    4096 May  9  2017 lib
drwxr-xr-x  2 root    root    4096 May  9  2017 local
drwxr-xr-x  3 root    root    4096 May  9  2017 lock
drwxr-xr-x  2 root    root    4096 May  9  2017 log
drwxr-xr-x  2 root    root    4096 May  9  2017 opt
drwxr-xr-x  2 root    root    4096 May  9  2017 run
drwxr-xr-x  3 root    root    4096 May  9  2017 spool
drwxrwxrwt  2 root    root    4096 May  9  2017 tmp
```

it will extract `4096` - the `jenkins_home` file size.

Things worth remembering:

- use simple bash scripts like `ls -la /var | grep jenkins_home | cut -d " " -f5`. The example you have shown above does not work in my local bash as well as in the Jenkins server
- add `returnStdout: true` parameter to `sh` step to return what your command prints to the console.

Comment: The directory size is just and example. I basically want to 1) issue a command that has column outputs like "ls -al", 2) find a line, 3) get the nth column in that line. Another example is "ps -ef" or "docker image ls"

Comment: I modified my question.

Comment: @ChrisF I've updated my answer. Two things are crucial: pipe bash script commands so they can return a correct output (your example does not work in my Jenkins and local bash env), use `returnStdout: true` to make `sh` step returning the output of the command so you can assign it to a variable.

Comment: Follow up question. How do I use the variable, DIR_SIZE in your example, OUTSIDE the script, as part of Groovy code in the stage? Or does the echo part illustrate this?

Comment: @ChrisF You can use it just like `echo` step does

Comment: Side note which might not be clear to new users - even if you had `node('other-agent')` and ran `new File('/var/jenkins_home/war/jsbundles')`, that Groovy code **executes on the Jenkins master, not on the agent/executor you specified**. It is also security checked for this reason and will fail by default in sandboxed pipelines