# Add shell script output value in a Jenkins ArrayList variable

Tags: shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, sh, jenkins-groovy

```
def path = ....
def files = []
sh "for file in $path/*.json; do files.add(file); done"
echo ${files}

Error I get in jenkins: /jenkins/workspace/....."syntax error near unexpected token 'file'
```

Can someone help me as to how can I add file in files? I tried looking for answers but couldn't find anything useful which solved my scenario.

I want to add the ***file*** variable inside Arraylist variable ***files*** so that I can fire curl command for each file in my Jenkins pipeline.
Also needed to know is there some way I can test the script before deploying it on any environment?

Comment: Bash has no access to Jenkins' variables. What you can do is have the shell script print the values and capture its output; though doing this in Jenkins directly would seem simpler and more straightforward.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50615649/how-to-get-the-output-of-a-shell-script-in-a-jenkinsfile shows some similar cases though not exactly a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a List JSON files in a directory as a List you can use the following code.

```
path = "/home/your/path"
dir(path) {
    def files = findFiles(glob: '**/*.json')
    println files.size()
    println files[0].name  
}
```